# RxJS share parent observable among partitioned child observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm coding a game in which the character can fire their weapon.
I want different things to happen when the player tries to fire, depending on whether they have ammo.

I reduced my issue down to the following code (btw I'm not sure why SO's snippet feature does not work, so I made [CodePen](https://codepen.io/getkey/pen/BqXgQR?editors=0012) where you can try out my code).

```js
const { from, merge } = rxjs;
const { partition, share, tap } = rxjs.operators;

let hasAmmo = true;
const [ fire$, noAmmo$ ] = from([true]).pipe(
  share(),
  partition(() => hasAmmo),
);


merge(
  fire$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      hasAmmo = false;
      console.log('boom');
    }),
  ),
  noAmmo$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log('bam');
    }),
  )
).subscribe({
  next: val => console.log('next', val),
  error: val => console.log('error', val),
  complete: val => console.log('complete', val),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

When I run this code I get the following:

```
"boom"
"next" true
"bam"
"next" true
"complete" undefined
```

**I don't understand why I get a `"bam"`.**

The first emission goes to `fire$` (I get a `"boom"`), which makes sense because `hasAmmo` is `true`. But as a side-effect of `fire$` emitting is that the result of the partition condition changes, which I guess is causing me to get a `"bam"`.

Am I not supposed to cause side-effects that affect `partition()`?

Or maybe is there an issue with the way I `share()` my parent observable? I may be wrong but I would intuitively think the `fire$` and `noAmmo$` internally subscribe to the parent in order to split it, in which case `share()` should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually works correctly. The confusion comes from the `partition` operator which is basically just [two `filter` operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/partition.ts#L50-L56).

If you rewrite it without `partition` it looks like this:

```
const fire$ = from([true]).pipe(
  share(),
  filter(() => hasAmmo),
);

const noAmmo$ = from([true]).pipe(
  share(),
  filter(() => !hasAmmo),
);
```

Be aware that changing `hasAmmo` has no effect on `partition` itself. `partition` acts only when it receives a value from its source Observable.

When you later use `merge()` it makes two separate subscriptions to two completely different chains with two different `from([true])`s. This means that `true` is passed to both `fire$` and `noAmmo$`.

So `share()` has no effect here. If you want to share it you'll have to wrap `from` before using it on `fire$` and `noAmmo$`. If the source Observable is just `from` it's unfortunately going to be even more confusing because the initial emission will arrive only to the first subscriber which is `fire$` later when used in `merge`:

```
const shared$ = from([true]).pipe(
  share(),
);

const fire$ = shared$.pipe(...);
const noAmmo$ = shared$.pipe(...);
```

The last thing why you're receiving both messages is that `partition` doesn't modify the value that goes through. It only decides which one of the returned Observable will reemit it.

Btw, rather avoid `partition` completely because it's probably going to be deprecated and just use `filter` which is more obvious:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3797
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3807

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The initial emission will indeed arrive to `fire$` first. Since all this is synchronous and `fire$`'s chain modifies hasAmmo, when `noAmmo$`'s chain runs right after, the filter condition is satisfied, which is not what I'm expecting. The solution here is to reorder the subscriptions, `noAmmo$` goes first since it cannot affect `fire$`, then `fire$`. I'm glad it's a relatively simple case, I can't imagine what I would have done if they all had the potential to affect each other! PS: in my real code `from([true])` is an event observable if it makes thing clearer.